# Which version of friendly Id gem to use with Rails 3.2.17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, friendly-id

I added following line into my gemfile as mentioned on the 4_stable_branch read me

```
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.10" # Note: You MUST use 4.0.9 or greater for Rails 3.2.10+
```

and bundle install, it shows following message

```
NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. If you're upgrading
from 3.x, please see this document:

http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md
```

I'm confused, which version of friendly_id to use in my rails 3.2.17 app.

If I upgrade my app to rails 4, will it cause problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is referring to friendly_id 3.x, not rails 3.x. If you had been using those older versions of friendly_id then you would have needed to make changes when upgrading to friendly_id 4.x

If you upgrade to rails 4 then you will need friendly_id 5.0.x

Comment: Thanks. I should've read the message. I'm using friendly_id 4 and it worked! If I upgrade my app to rails 4, do I need to make changes to my app other than changing friendly_id version to 5.0.x

Comment: Some of the defaults have changed - see http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/#Upgrading_from_FriendlyId_4_0